# New IMG Class in CSS

Tags: css, image, class

I'm trying to create a new img class so I can add properties to it without affecting the original img class.

example:

```
<img class="Test" src="www.google.com"/>
```

Can anyone advise how I can do this in CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple classes on an HTML element, seperated by a space. It than gets styles from both.
So in HTML:

```
<img class="old" src="image.jpg">
<img class="old new" src="image.jpg">
```

And CSS:

```
.old { width: 100px; }
.new { height: 50px; }
```

While the first image only has a width assigned, the second also has a height definition.

Answer (score 0):

The class attribute allows for a space-delimited list of classes that are applied to the element.

For example, the following will result in an image that is 40px wide by 20px high:

**HTML**

```
<img class="Test another-class" src="www.google.com"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.Test {
    width: 40px;
}
.another-class {
    height: 20px;
}
```